# VSCode C# intellisense not working for mono/winforms

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, visual-studio-code, mono

I just installed mono to use WinForms. WinForms itself works great but there is no autocomplete and it doesn't detect anything related to WinForms, I can't see what "." options I have for any WinForms-related object. Instead it fills it in with other standard C# stuff when I'm trying to write things. Anyone had a similar problem or knows a fix for this? Thanks in advance.

For reference, I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and VSCode with Vim emulator.

Comment: Do you actually have the proper dll's referenced? Intellisesne and Refactoring can only consider what is in DLL that are added as references and this one might not be added by default.

Comment: @Christopher Thank you! That was it. I just had to reference it in .csproj. I thought it would do that by itself since it's in the same place as all other System. things.